# How to create a table (or list) with the order codes of orders with both products

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a `Transactions` table with the following structure:

```
ID  | Product | OrderCode | Value
1   |   8     | ABC       | 100
2   |   5     | ABC       | 150
3   |   4     | ABC       |  80
4   |   5     | XPT       | 100
5   |   6     | XPT       | 100
6   |   8     | XPT       | 100
7   |   5     | XYZ       | 100
8   |   8     | UYI       |  90
```

How do I create a table (or list) with the order codes of orders with both products 5 and 8?

In the example above it should be the orders `ABC` and `XPT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this, but here's a fairly general solution what I came up with:

```
FilteredList =
    VAR ProductList = {5, 8}
    VAR SummaryTable = SUMMARIZE(Transactions,
                           Transactions[OrderCode],
                           "Test",
                           COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(ProductList, VALUES(Transactions[Product])))
                               = COUNTROWS(ProductList))
    RETURN SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(SummaryTable, [Test]), "OrderCode", Transactions[OrderCode])
```

The key here is if the set of products for a particular order code contains both `5` and `8`, then the intersection of `VALUES(Transations[Product])` with the set `{5,8}` is exactly that set and has a count of `2`. If it doesn't have both, the count will be `1` or `0` and the test fails.

Comment: Bravo! It took me a while to get there but I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate more on your question, From your above post I understood is you want to filter the list, For that, you can use below code

```
List<Transactions> listTransactions = listTransactions.FindAll(x=>x.Product == 5 || x.Product == 8)
```

Comment: I need to know which orders have both products 5 and 8. Using Power BI Desktop filters and only select orders that contain those products but not necessarily the ones with BOTH products.